# CSS selector of link to the next page returns empty list in Scrapy shell

Tags: css, scrapy, href, scrapy-shell

I'm new in Scrapy.
I try to get link to the next page from this site https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/?section_id=1592

What how html looks like: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08KNv.png)

In scrapy shell I wrote this command:

```
response.css('li.pagination__button-item._next a::attr(href)')
```

It returns an empty list.

I have also tried

```
response.css('a.pagination__item._link._button._next.smartLink')
```

but it also returns an empty list.

I will be grateful for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is generated with JavaScript, see how it look with 'view(response)'.

```
# with css:
In [1]: response.css('head > link:nth-child(28) ::attr(href)').get()                                                   
Out[1]: 'https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/page-2/'

# with xpath:
In [2]: response.xpath('//link[@rel="next"]/@href').get()
Out[2]: 'https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/page-2/'
```

Comment: Its work fine.how to find it?

Comment: Open the webpage with 'view(response)', open devtools and search the url (or part of it).

Comment: @SuperUser thank you! It works. But how do you find "nth-child(28)"? In 'view(response)' I can see this element: "<link data-n-head="ssr" rel="next" href="https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/page-2/">" and can't find "nth-child(28)".

Comment: In DevTools right click and choose copy xpath, or copy css selector.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add to [@SuperUser's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16429780/superuser) answer. Seeing as the site loads the HTML via JavaScript, please read the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html) on how to handle JavaScript websites. [`scrapy-playwright`](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright) is a recent library that I have found to be quite fast and easy to use when scraping JS rendered sites.